# Regex to replace part of a String in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have string like this:

```
Hello &3 are &4 you &k here?
```

And I want to replace &x with "", but I don't know how because after each & there always could be random letter or number. I tried something like this:

```
"Hello &3 are &4 you &k here?".replaceAll("[&.*]", "")
```

But it definitely doesn't work this way ^^

Comment: Please read the [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class javadoc.

Comment: Please state what you mean when you say: "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Hello &3 are &4 you &k here?".replaceAll("\\&.", "");
```

is the code you are looking for. It will match a literal "&" and another single character after it and replace that.

[image]

Comment: @user2638742 Right, `\\`, not `\`. Or just forgo the backslashes completely.

Comment: @user2638742 Please use the checkmark next to my answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("&\\w? ", "");
```

You said there *could* be an letter or number after the &, so I made that optional. If there's always a letter/number, remove the question mark.